# The type or namespace name 'TwilioRestClient' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

This is what I did:

went to 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/tutorials/account-verification-csharp-mvc

downloaded the code and built the code using VS2017 community edition.
I get the following error in IdentityConfig.cs

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TwilioRestClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  AccountVerification.Web C:\Users\admin\Downloads\account-verification-csharp-master\account-verification-csharp-master\AccountVerification.Web\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs  21  Active`

What is the problem?

I changed nothing. Just downloaded and built the code. Shouldn't you guys give a working copy of the code?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get this working by following these steps:

1. Close the solution in Visual Studio if you have it opened.
2. Ensure you have a nuget CLI in your path. So you can run a restore from a command prompt. This is pretty straightforward. Instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#windows).
3. Open a command prompt at the solution directory. (**C:\Users\admin\Downloads\account-verification-csharp-master\account-verification-csharp-master** for you.)
4. Run a nuget restore. `nuget restore` and wait for it to finish.
5. You should get all the packages downloaded at the packages directory under your solution folder.

   > UPDATE - Looking at the code it appears that there's a mix of features from the latest version 5.x and the now deprecated version 4.x, and that's causing compilation errors. Details [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/migrating-your-csharp-dot-net-application-twilio-sdk-4x-5x).

### Follow the below steps to downgrade the version to 4.7.2:

6. Open the solution file now.
7. Right-click the web project and select **Manage Nuget Packages**.
8. Search for **Twilio** and downgrade the version from 5.x to 4.7.2.

   a) Or from the **Package Manager Console `Install-Package Twilio -Version 4.7.2`**
9. Solution should build successfully now.
10. Please bear in mind that you must setup the parameters in **Local.config** file before the app can work. It'll run though, but you'll not be able to go through it until the parameters are properly set.

**Note:** The solution contains a file named **Local.config.example**. When you open the solution you'll notice that **Local.config** file is missing.

[image: missing Local.config file]

Renaming the existing **Local.config.example** file to **Local.config** solves that issue. I had to copy the Local.config file to the test project too. This doesn't prevent the solution from building, though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did exactly as you said.. I downloaded the nuget.exe under this folder C:\Users\admin\Downloads\account-verification-csharp-master\account-verification-csharp-master and ran the nuget restore command  and I got the following message ''all packages listed in packages.config are already installed" . I tried rebuilding the project only to get the same error.

Comment: @Venkat, you're right. I think I forgot the step I took to downgrade the Twilio package to the v.4.7.2. That should definitely do the trick. It did it for me. Anyways, let me know if it still doesn't work for you. See the UPDATED steps.